# Delete first occurance Doubly Linked List Java

Tags: java, doubly-linked-list

Could someone tell me what's missing in my code. I am trying to remove the first occurrence of a given node value.

It fails very few test cases, but I am not sure what I am missing. Here is my code :

```
public boolean remove(E obj) {
    if (obj == null)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Violation of precondition : remove(E obj)");
    DoubleListNode<E> current = head;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i ++) {
        if (current.getData().equals(obj)) {
            E result = remove(i);
            return true;
        }
        current = current.getNext();
    }
    size --;
    return false;
}
```

Comment: "It fails test cases" isn't a very specific description of the error. You need to take the time to debug your problem and determine _what's_ not working. If you get to a spot where you see A happening in a specific place, but you think it should be B, then that could be a good question for this site (if it's not already asked in another question). I understand this is hard, I really do... but it's part of your assignment, and more importantly, it's a critical part of programming. Debugging is only going to get harder as your programs get more complex, so you may as well start the process now.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the full source code as a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others, that shows the error you get.

Answer (score 0):

That recursive call to remove() inside the if block looks wrong.

You are already inside the list, you identified the first matching object. So now your code has to really remove that matching object. Removing would mean to update both links accordingly.

Do these things on paper! Draw a double linked list with nodes and the links between them. Then ask yourself what removing a node that has one or two links coming in (and potentially going out) actually means. You will have to change the links from the previous node and the one following the node that is to removed!